Add a tikzpicture to every pages except the first and last one
I want to add a tikzpicture (in the example below a circle at the top of the page) to every page in my article, except for the first and last page. I am using \AtBeginShipout, but how can I exclude certain pages using \AtBeginShipout?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Circle}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw[green, fill=green](-1.75, 1.75) circle (0.28);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\Circle}}


\begin{document}
    \section{Intro}
    \label{sec:Intro}
        No circle.
        \clearpage

    \section{Main results}
    \label{sec:Main}
        \lipsum[2-6] % CIRCLE ON THIS PAGE

    \clearpage
    \section{End}
    \label{sec:End}
        No circle.

\end{document}


The first page is easy.  The last page takes two runs.
BTW, you don't need [remember picture] since you are not using (curent page).  You do need [overlay] if you want the picture placed relative to (0,0) instead of the lower left corner.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{atbegshi}% obsolete, redundant
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref

\newcommand{\Circle}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \draw[green, fill=green](-1.75, 1.75) circle (0.28);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifnum\value{page}=1
\else
  \ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\relax
  \else
    \put(1in,-1in){\Circle}%
  \fi
\fi}


\begin{document}
    \section{Intro}
    \label{sec:Intro}
        No circle.
        \clearpage

    \section{Main results}
    \label{sec:Main}
        \lipsum[2-6] % CIRCLE ON THIS PAGE

    \clearpage
    \section{End}
    %\pageref{LastPage}
    \label{sec:End}
        No circle.

\end{document}


Works like a charm, thanks!
